# Disable background while spinner/loader is running

Tags: css, reactjs

I used [React-spinners](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spinners) but the problem that is background is not disabled when loader is working.

Tried to achieve that by css so I added:

```
.parentDisable{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #666;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 998;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and used it from my loader:

```
.centered {
  position: absolute; /* or fixed */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```
import { css } from '@emotion/core';

const override = css`
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-color: red;
`;
```

```
<div className='sweet-loading centered parentDisable'>
    <PropagateLoader
        css={override}
        sizeUnit={"px"}
        size={25}
        // color={'#123abc'}
        color={'#0062ff'}
        loading={this.state.loading}
    />
</div>
```

But I'm facing some issues:

1) The spinner is not aligned to center anymore... it's on the top left corner

2) After spinner stops the overlay background remains on the screen

I solved second issue by doing:

```
 <div /*className='sweet-loading centered parentDisable'*/ className={this.state.loading ? 'parentDisable' : ''}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution in case someone will need it:

```
 <div className={this.state.loading ? 'parentDisable' : ''} width="100%">
                        <div className='overlay-box'>
                            <PropagateLoader
                                // css={override}
                                sizeUnit={"px"}
                                size={25}
                                color={'white'}
                                loading={this.state.loading}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS#

```
.parentDisable{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #666;
  opacity: 0.8;
  z-index: 998;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.overlay-box {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white; background: #666666; opacity: .8;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```